# How to count passed hours in format like this hh:mm - hh:mm?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table like this

```
------------------------------------------
   id     |    work hours   |   pause   
------------------------------------------
    1.    |  07:00-17:00    |   30 min
-------------------------------------------
    2.    |  06:00-12:00    |    1h
-------------------------------------------
    3.    |  08:30-16:00    |    30 min
```

I want to get passed hours for this format 07:00-17:00 (that id 10 hours) and that value substract with "pause" (10h - 30m). Do that with all rows and at the end get the sum of all rows.

Is it possible to do that with mysql, or with PHP?

Comment: Also is this your own database? If so I'd strongly recommend storing your data in a better format to begin with. Split each value into a separate field and also store everything in a consistent easily parseable format. Use the native [time](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) type, ideally.

Comment: I am stuck with both, I am still junior with mysql and I know this will be a little complicated query.

Comment: ok so...have you attempted to research any of it? First you need to split the "work hours" into two parts (using the `-`). Then parse each part as a time. Then find a way to convert the "pause" values into a time (might be trickier). Then you can do the necessary maths on them easily using mysql's built-in date and time.functions. Lastly you can use SQL Sum to get the final value. You shouldn't need PHP. Now the task is broken down into small steps it should be easier to research each one, write a small bit of code to do that, verify it, and that way build up the solution bit by bit.

Comment: If you view it as one big problem then of course it's complicated but if you view it as lots of small problems then it's much easier to deal with. Give it a go. If you get stuck with a specific bit, then come and talk to us.

Comment: (You might find someone answers below if they are expert enough to write this in a few seconds, or did something similar previously, but in general you find you get a better response to your questions if you have at least [done some investigation and attempts yourself first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). With modern search engines, finding documentation and examples is usually quite easy - as long as you search for the generic small building blocks of the program, rather than your specific overall goal.)

Comment: P.S. also your question says "is there a way"...to which the answer is simply "yes". But I suspect that isn't really the response you want...consider re-writing your question to be more specific, focused on a particular issue, and not eliciting a binary response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
SELECT id, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIMEDIFF(to_time, from_time), pause)))) AS time_diff
FROM (
  SELECT id,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(work_hours, '-', 1) AS TIME) AS from_time,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(work_hours, '-', -1) AS TIME) AS to_time,
    CAST(CASE WHEN INSTR(pause, 'h') THEN CONCAT(TRIM(REPLACE(pause, 'h', '')) , ':00:00') ELSE CONCAT('00:', TRIM(REPLACE(pause, 'min', '')), ':00') END AS TIME) AS pause
  FROM t
) t GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP
```

[**1st demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6ff52232e3ca047c2bfb5b4921534c2e)
[**2nd demo on dbfiddle.uk (*sum of half hours*)**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b7507d9236377dd6a17e99e45b9238e2)

This solution is using a `SELECT` on the `FROM` part to get the information of the columns in the right format. To `SUM` up all the time differences you can use a `GROUP BY` on the `id` column with [`WITH ROLLUP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html).

**You can `SUM` the time differences up to around 838 hours:**

> `TIME` values may range from `-838:59:59` to `838:59:59`. The hours part may be so large because the `TIME` type can be used not only to represent a time of day (which must be less than 24 hours), but also elapsed time or a time interval between two events (which may be much greater than 24 hours, or even negative).
>   ***source:*** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html

---

**I recommend to change your table structure! It is better to save the time values ​​in their own column (using [`TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) datatype instead of string).**

You can create a table using this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table (
  id INT,
  work_hours_from TIME,
  work_hours_to TIME,
  pause TIME
);
```

Using the following `INSERT` command you can transfer all (valid) rows of your current table to the new table:

```
INSERT INTO new_table
SELECT id,
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(work_hours, '-', 1) AS TIME) AS from_time,
  CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(work_hours, '-', -1) AS TIME) AS to_time,
  CAST(CASE WHEN INSTR(pause, 'h') THEN CONCAT(TRIM(REPLACE(pause, 'h', '')) , ':00:00') ELSE CONCAT('00:', TRIM(REPLACE(pause, 'min', '')), ':00') END AS TIME) AS pause
FROM old_table
```

Now you can write an easier `SELECT` query without using string functions to get the expected result:

```
SELECT id, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(TIMEDIFF(work_hours_to, work_hours_from), pause)))) AS time_diff
FROM new_table
GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, but I have found problem with this, when i have like this 00:30 ,  00:30 , 00:30 ... it counts 00:90 and not 01:30. How to fix that?

Answer (score -1):

Avoid using directly time to store in database. This can cause a serious issue for many day. For example 01/01/2019 23:00 and 02/01/2019 02:00

If you have not store the full date, your code will not work.

```
$timeStart = YOUR_FULL_DATE_TIME_START;
$timeEnd = YOUR_FULL_DATE_TIME_END;

$pause = YOUR_PAUSE_IN_SECOND;
//duration in second
$duration = $timeEnd->getTimestamp() - ($timeStart->getTimestamp() + $pause);
//you can easily convert $duration
```

Comment: you've entirely misunderstood the nature of the data in the question. It's a schedule, not a specific point in time. Storing a date here would be counterproductive.